# Verificar se uma ID existe numa data-list

Tags: jquery, html

Estou fazendo um crud ajax onde usuário escolhe um resultado vindo de uma data-list para ser adicionado a uma tabela(html).

data-list

```
     <div class="list_details">
       <ul>
        <li id="valor"><img src="..."><p>Nome</p></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="valor"><img src="..."><p>Nome</p></li>
        <hr>
        <li id="valor"><img src="..."><p>Nome</p></li>
        <hr>
      </ul>      
    </div>
```

Ao clicar em uma das `li` um evento é disparado:

```
$('.list_details li').on('click',function(){
   if(! $('.tab_aluno').find('tr').attr('id') == $(this).attr('id') ){
      $('.tab_aluno').before('<tr class='+$(this).attr("id")+'><td><img src="'+$(this).find('img').attr('src')+'"></td><td>'+$(this).find('p').text()+'</td><td class="remove">X</td></tr>');  
   }
   $('.list_details').hide();
});
```

O código pra fazer insert nas tabelas funciona, porém quero verificar na propria tabela se a id já foi incluída. Ai onde o bicho pega, na hora de fazer esse "SE A ID EXISTIR NA TABELA"

O código acima vai gerar algo como:

```
<table class="tab_aluno">
  <tr id="id">
     <td><img src="..."></td>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td class='remove'>X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="id">
     <td><img src="..."></td>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td class='remove'>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Portanto, estou procurando uma lógica para o if, para que ele pesquisa em todas as `<tr>` já existentes na `<table>` e verifique se a id já foi incluída para evitar resultados duplicados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Será isto que quer?

```
$('.list_details li').on('click',function(){
   var cliked = $(this);
   var found = false;
   $('.tab_aluno tr').each(function(){
     if($(this).attr('id') == cliked.attr('id')) {
         found = true;
         return false; // sair do loop
     }
   });
   if(found) {
      alert('id existe');
   }
   else {
       $('.tab_aluno').before('<tr id="'+cliked.attr("id")+'" class="'+cliked.attr("id")+'"><td><img src="'+cliked.find('img').attr('src')+'"></td><td>'+cliked.find('p').text()+'</td><td>X</td></tr>');  
   }
   $('.list_details_a').hide();
});
```

Comment: não é exatamente isso, esqueci de mencionar que no código há uma `<table>` vazia, que vai sendo populada a medida que o usuario clica na data-list. essa data-list é montada dinamicamente com busca por palavra. o que eu quero é evitar que uma mesmo resultado encontado na data-lista seja inserido mais de uma vez na tabela

Comment: Entendi, veja se é isso. Editei a minha resposta

Comment: Ainda não. Ao clicar na data list consigo obter o valor da id sem problemas. Estou tentando pegar essa id e fazer uma busca dentro da `<table>` pra ver se o valor já foi atribuido a uma das suas `<tr>`

Comment: Editei. Mudei os elementos a percorrer. Em vez dos `li` vamos percorrer a `table` (`.tab_aluno`)

Comment: Adicionei também um id à `<tr>`, você só estava a adicionar uma class. Precisa mesmo dessa classe na nova `<tr>` gerada?

Comment: minha nossa, olha essa classe aí no `<tr>` , muito provavelmente esse era o problema, passei pelo código umas 20 vezes e nao vi a classe

Comment: realmente era a questão do class, porém a estrutura proposta também ajudou a otimizar o código, obrigado!

Comment: Ainda bem que ajudou